# php select variable cfrom data base

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to select some variable from database and then insert them. But how to change maybe or idk do something because where i try to insert "VALUES ('m.ID', 'md.ID')" he dont recognize and its not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT m.vardas, m.pavarde, m.ID, md.pavadinimas, md.ID FROM  Mokinys m, Mokymodalykas md
where m.vardas='$mokiniovar' and m.pavarde='$mokiniopav' and md.pavadinimas='$dalykas'";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO Pazymiuregistras (mokinio_ID, dalyko_ID, pazymys, data) VALUES ('$m.ID', '$md.ID', '$pazymys', '$data');"; // in this place he dont recognize m.id and md.id
if ($conn->multi_query($sql2) === TRUE) {
echo "New records created successfully";
} else{
echo "Error";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: And what is `$m`?

Comment: I think it's variable from which database table I take

Answer (score 0):

Use a single statement `insert . . . select`.  Don't do this with a loop!

```
INSERT INTO Pazymiuregistras (mokinio_ID, dalyko_ID, pazymys, data) 
    SELECT m.ID, md.ID, '$pazymys', '$data'
    FROM  Mokinys m CROSS JOIN
          Mokymodalykas md
    WHERE m.vardas = '$mokiniovar' AND
          m.pavarde = '$mokiniopav' AND
          md.pavadinimas = '$dalykas';
```

In addition, get out of the habit of dumping strings into SQL statements.  Learn to use parameters.  This is important for two reasons:

1. Putting strings into the statements can cause unexpected syntax errors, and occasionally hard-to-find bugs.
2. The resulting code is at risk of SQL-injection attacks.